# anchor tag div name

Tags: html, css

I'm running into some trouble here, all help appreciated. I'm trying to link to a certain section on my page. But I'm having trouble. check my code:

```
<a href="#h2">Consulting</a>
```

That's the link, here's the block I'm wanting to link to:

```
<div class="space" name="h2">
  <h1 class="h2">Consulting</h1>    
  <p class="paragraph">BLAH</p> 
</div>
```

Now I think I have it wrong, but I'm trying not to keep it messy. But would I have to do

```
<a name="h2">BLAH</a>
```

to make it work, or can I do what I was doing, and am I missing something?

Comment: Use id instead of class

Answer (score 1):

With [URL fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) you want to target the ID, not the class. Change it to:

```
<div class="space" name="h2">
  <h1 id="h2" class="h2">Consulting</h1>    
  <p class="paragraph">BLAH</p> 
</div>
```

Per MDN:

> A URL fragment is a name preceded by a hash mark (#), which specifies
>   an internal target location (**an ID**) within the current document.

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: Oh wow, I knew it was something simple, can't believe this. Thank you again buddy!

Comment: `name` is not a valid attribute for `div`.